# Lazy loading reference implementation

Tags: java, reference, lazy-loading, guava

Being impressed by Guava's [computing map feature](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#makeComputingMap%28com.google.common.base.Function%29), I'm searching for a sort of "computing reference" - a lazy loading reference implementation that parallel's Guava's ease of use, by which I mean it handles all locking, loading, and exception handling under the hood, only exposing a `get()` method.

After a brief search turned up nothing, I quickly rolled my own as a proof of concept:

```
public abstract class ComputingRef<T> implements Callable<T> {

   private volatile T referent = null;
   private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

   public T get() {
      T temp = referent;
      if (temp == null) {
         lock.lock();
         try {
            temp = referent;
            if (temp == null) {
               try {
                  referent = temp = call();
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                  if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
                     throw (RuntimeException)e;
                  }
                  else {
                     throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         finally {
            lock.unlock();
         }
      }
      return temp;
   }
}
```

This `ComputingRef` could be anonymously extended to implement `call()`, which functions as the factory method:

```
ComputingRef<MyObject> lazySingletonRef = new ComputingRef<MyObject>() {
   @Override
   public MyObject call() {
      //fetch MyObject from database and return
   }
};
```

I'm not satisfied that this implementation is optimal, but it demonstrates what I'm after.

I later found [this example from the T2 Framework](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/LazyLoadingReference.htm), which appears to be more complex.

Now my questions are:

- How can my above code be improved?
- How does it compare to the T2 example, and what advantages are offered by that example's greater complexity?
- Are there other implementations of a lazy loading reference that I've missed in my search?

**EDIT:** Updated my implementation to use a local variable as suggested by [@irreputable's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524423/lazy-loading-reference-implementation/7524565#7524565) - please upvote it if you find the above example useful.

Comment: If you're on Java 5 & up, why not just use an [`AtomicReference`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)?

Comment: @AlistairIsrael - I may be mistaken, but `AtomicReference` doesn't seem to support lazy loading on its own.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael - Or did you mean I should use it instead of `volatile` in my code example?

Comment: Yup, have your `ComputingMap` use an internal `AtomicReference` instead of having a lock and implementing double-checked locking yourself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See [`Suppliers.memoize(Supplier)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize-com.google.common.base.Supplier-) to lazily initialize a value.

Comment: +1 Ah, completely missed this. I notice `MemoizingSupplier` uses a volatile boolean `initialized` rather than having the value volatile and checking it for null. How does this compare to the typical double check locking idiom?

Comment: Pretty much the same, but a supplier may return null so it can't be used to indicate initialization.

Comment: Is the same possible to achieve using standard Java 8 libraries?

Comment: There's also this implementation of LazyReference which handles exceptions in the initialisation although it's old now: https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-util-concurrent/0.0.7/apidocs/index.html?com/atlassian/util/concurrent/LazyReference.html

Anyone got a better implementation that handles exceptions during initialisation?

Answer (score 2):

It's the good old double-checked locking idiom. You should add a local variable for performance. In your impl, you have 2 volatile reads in the fast path (when referent is set). Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: +1 Excellent article, thank you. I'll update my question and cite your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, here's how I would do it (and then I'd worry about performance later):

```
public abstract class ComputingRef<T> implements Callable<T> {

    private final AtomicReference<T> ref = new AtomicReference<T>();

    public T get() {
        if (ref.get() == null) {
            try {
                final T newValue = call();
                if (ref.compareAndSet(null, newValue)) {
                    return newValue;
                }
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    throw (RuntimeException) e;
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

        }
        return ref.get();
    }
}
```

The only 'snag' with this approach is that there is a race condition that could result multiple instantiations of the referent object (esp. if the `ComputingRef` is shared across a large number of threads that all hit `get()` at the same time). If instantiating the referent class is so expensive or you want to avoid multiple-instantiation at all costs, then I'd go with your double-checked locking as well.

You also have to make sure that the referent object cleans up after itself. Otherwise, if the `compareAndSet()` fails, then make sure to perform any necessary cleanup.

(Note that if the referent needs to be a singleton, then I'd use the [initialization on demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) instead.)